# What is the probabilty of selecting two random numbers from 0 to N-1 with positive difference

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I am new to probabilities and I am trying to solve the following problem:

> We randomly select two numbers from $0$ to $N-1$ for $N = 1, 2, \dots$. What is the probability function of $P(n)$, where $n$ is the difference of the two numbers selected, given that $n$ greater or equal to zero? Prove that the probability is normalized to one.

Intuitively, I found that $P(n)$ is $\frac{N-n}{N^2}$. Is it possible to reach this result by applying a theorem?

Also how can be possible, the requested probability to sum to $14$, given that the we select only the positive deferences? I am thinking for example, that if I roll two dice, then the differences I can have vary from $-5$ to $5$, and the sum of their probabilities is one. How can be possible the sum of a subtotal of the possible events (as the positive differences) to sum to one? Do I miss something?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You should format your post by surrounding all mathematical expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs.  Then `$N^2$` will show up as $N^2$.  For more information, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ denote the two selected numbers then it seems to me that you must find $P(n)=P(|X-Y|=n)$. Then $\sum_{n\geq0}P(n)=1$. If $Q(n):=P(X-Y=n)$ then $\sum_{n}Q(n)=1$ with $P(0)=Q(0)$ and $P(n)=Q(n)+Q(-n)$ for $n\geq1$. Is your interpretation different?

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm interpreting the problem right, but it seems that your formula for $P(n)$ for $n=0,1,...N-1$ would be right if you multiply it by $2$ EXCEPT for the case of $n=0$. The idea is that each non-double occurs twice in the $NxN$ matrix of all the possible pairs in $X x Y$.

Comment: Or maybe you mean conditional probability, i.e. find $P(Y-X = n | X<=Y )$, which means your denominator $N^2$ isn't right, since $N^2$ counts ALL pairs $(X,Y)$. There are $N$ pairs with $X=Y$, and half of the others have $X<Y$, and if you adjust your denominator accordingly, you'll have probabilities which sum to $1$.